# has_one and belongs to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, has-one

I'm rather new to rails and I'm stuck with this has_one and belongs_to form. I'm trying to create a team that has two speakers (from class 'User') through a form ,in the following manner:

```
class Team<ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :league
belongs_to :seed
has_many :speakers do 
def user(level="1")
    find_by(level: level).user
end
```

end
    end

my user model looks like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :team

end
```

user model:
    class User

speaker model:

```
class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :user
end
```

my issue is (i think ) primarily in my controllers and form.controller looks like:

```
class TeamsController<ApplicationController


def new
    @seed=Seed.find_by_id(params[:seed_id])
    @league=current_admin.league
    @team=current_admin.league.teams.build(:seed_id=>@seed,:approved=>false)
    @usernames= @mca.connections.connected.each do |x| x.user end
end

def create
    @league=current_admin.league
    @team = @league.teams.build(team_params)

  if @team.save
    flash[:notice] = "Team Request Sent!."
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to request team."
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

end

form looks like:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_for @team do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :seed_id, :value => @seed.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :league_id, :value => @league.id %>

            <div class="row">
                <!-- <div class="col-md-8"> -->
                <div class="form-group">

                    <%= f.collection_select :speaker, @usernames,:user,:fullname, multiple:true %>
                </div>



                <!-- </div> -->
            </div>


            <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit "Create" , class:"btn btn-primary" %>
            </div>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate some help because it keeps throwing the following error:

NoMethodError in TeamsController#create 
undefined method `each' for "2":String

Comment: @RichPek, I have updated my code to yours and have updated the new error

Answer (score 1):

The surface issue you have is that you're passing a *string* when Rails is expecting an *object*:

> User(#69980837338020) expected, got String(#69980808947560)

This means you should be sending `@user` rather than "username" etc.

The error will likely be on this line:

```
@team = @league.teams.build team_params
```

... which means that you're passing `:speaker` (which Rails needs as an *object*) when you should be passing the `speaker_id` foreign key. `Yury Lebedev`'s answer explains how to do this.

---

There is a deeper issue.

I don't see how each `User` can only belong to a `Team`:

```
class AddFieldsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :speaker_id, :integer
    add_column :users, :speaker2_id, :integer
  end
end
```

For this to work, your users can *only* be a member of **one** team.

Whilst this might work for a smaller scale product, I personally feel it to be an incorrect schema setup.

If *anything*, you'd expect the `team` to have `speaker_1` and `speaker_2`, which would mean those two options being stored in the `teams` database (not user).

I think *this* is the cause of your problem (you're trying to set the `speaker_1` and `speaker_2` params when they don't exist in the `teams` db).

-

I would recommend the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :speaking_engagements, class_name: "Speaker"
   has_many :teams, through: :speaking_engagements
end

#app/models/speaker.rb
class Speaker < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns team_id | user_id | level | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :team
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :speakers do
      def user(level="1")
         find_by(level: level).user
      end
   end
end
```

This will give you the ability to call:

```
@team = Team.find params[:id]
@speakers = @team.speakers

@user.speaking_engagements.where(team: @team)
```

To save it, you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/teams_controller.rb
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      ...
       @team = current_admin.league.teams.build seed: @seed, approved: false
   end

   def create
       @league = current_admin.league
       @team = @league.teams.build team_params

       if @team.save
         ...
   end

   private

   def team_params
       params.require(:team).permit(:name, :speakers) #-> not sure about "speakers"
   end
end
```

This should allow you to define the following:

```
#app/views/teams/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @team do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :speakers, @usernames, :id, :name, multiple: true %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @RichPeck, 
As I said, I'm a beginner. I appreciate you answer very much and I am in the process of running it in my system. If you could, please tell me what this does? 

#app/models/team.rb
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :speakers do
      def user(level="1")
         find_by(level: level).user
      end
   end
end

Comment: It's called an [Activerecord Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions) - it basically allows you to call `@team.speakers.user`

Comment: Thanks for that RichPeck, 
I ran your code, however the following error pops up when using ":speakers" in the teams_controller:
undefined method `each' for "2":String

Comment: can you give more context? Which method throws the error?

Comment: But then , when I user ":speaker", it works fine , and in the console when I check Team.all.first.speaker, it returns nil. 
Team.all.first.speakers returns an error (Undefined method speakers for Team)

Comment: You'll have to post updated code - sounds like you haven't updated your model

Comment: NoMethodError in TeamsController#create 

thats the error for ":speakers" in team_params

Comment: Is there a migration that I need to do/undo maybe?

Comment: If it helps , here's the error Rich: 
 NoMethodError in TeamsController#create 
undefined method `each' for "3":String

and the parameters are:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"3W5c33q7i7d9hkp/xNKtchzzuHrrHvlQSrjafBcoNdXAOB3YUXDHWrNoKCSwVoSwcpf2uOW1wfR4ppGRL4hNLA==",
 "team"=>{"seed_id"=>"9",
 "league_id"=>"12",
 "speakers"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Create"}

If there are three users and I select only one, why are 3 users appearing for the :speakers parameter?
Please help me solve this, I'm kind of stuck on this for quite sometime.
Thanks